# LINQ OrderBy not sorting

Tags: .net, lambda, sql-order-by

I have a Customer class that has a ListOf Orders. I am trying to sort all the orders by date. The date "order_date" is string in YYYY:MM:DD HH:MM:SS" format.

Here is the code Lambda expression:

```
Dim orders() = Customer.Orders.ToArray().OrderBy(Function(c) c.order_date).ToArray()
```

This doesn't seems to be sorting the date.

I tried to convert to DateTime which works fine if the order_date is null or has some value but if an order_date date is blank then it throws an exception.

```
Dim orders() = Customer.Orders.OrderBy(Function(c) (Not String.IsNullOrEmpty(c.order_date))).ThenBy(Function(c) Convert.ToDateTime(c.order_date)).ToArray()
```

Comment: What's the problem of first way? what is input/output?

Comment: Output is same as input?

Comment: yes. sorting is not happening

Answer (score 0):

I can see you're using VB I use C# but you should be able to translate

```
var orders = Customer.Orders.ToList().Sort((a,b)=> a.order_date.Compare(b.order_date))
```

MSDN has a full article [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/w56d4y5z.aspx)

If you are trying to use Linq2Sql/Entities then and you want to orderby on the database before getting them back in memory. You don't need to do the ToArray() before sorting. also consider using linq syntax for code that occurs on the database. it makes it clear to developers where you are querying

```
 var orders = (from o in DataContext.Orders
              where o.Customer.Id == customerId
              orderby o.order_date
              select o)
```

Here is another example

```
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        var dates = new List<DateTime?>()
                    {
                        null,
                        null,
                        new DateTime(2001, 2, 3),
                        null,
                        new DateTime(2001, 12, 3),
                        new DateTime(2021, 12, 3)
                    };

         dates.Sort(CompareDates);

    }

    private static int CompareDates(DateTime? x, DateTime? y)
    {
        if (x == null)
        {
            return y == null ? 0 : -1;
        }
        return y == null ? 1 : x.Value.CompareTo(y.Value);
    }
```

Comment: What's a difference between implicitly or explicitly call to `Comapre` method?

Comment: Does that mean i have to write a Compare Function. The line Customer.Orders.ToList().Sort((a,b)=> a.order_date.Compare(b.order_date))
 doesn't compile

Comment: I put together an full example for you with a compare method that uses Nullable DateTime